# Form submits data locally but not remotely

Tags: php, forms, pdo

I have a very simple form that sends data to another page to then check it exists before inserting it into the database. It works perfectly in MAMP on a local environment but on the server it won't insert any data. It seems to not be sending any data becuase when I remove the **isset** checks it runs the program but inserts blank field into the database.

I do not understand why it won't work. Security is not an issue.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="input.php">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="nombre" id="nombre"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apellido</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="apellido" id="apellido"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td>Correo</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="correo" id="correo"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td>Telefono</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="telefono" id="telefono"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nivel de interés</td>
      <td><select name="nivel" id="nivel"><option value="none">Elige uno</option><option value="Licenciatura">Licenciatura</option><option value="Maestria">Maestría</option><option value="Doctorado">Doctorado</option><option value="Curso de ingles">Curso de inglés</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td>Universidad</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="universidad" id="universidad"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td>Hoy</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" name="fecha" id="fecha" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td></td>
      <td><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Guardar"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  $nombre = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['nombre']));
  $apellido = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['apellido']));
  $correo = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['correo']));
  $telefono = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['telefono']));
  $nivel = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['nivel']));
  $universidad = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['universidad']));
  $fecha = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fecha']));

  if($nombre == '' || $apellido == '' || $correo == '' || $telefono == '' || $nivel == '' || $universidad == '' || $fecha == '') {
    header('Location: fallo.php');
  } else {

    $db = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    $data = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ferias (nombre, apellido, correo, telefono, nivel, universidad, fecha) VALUES (:nombre, :apellido, :correo, :telefono, :nivel, :universidad, :fecha)");
    $data->execute(array(
      'nombre' => $nombre,
      'apellido' => $apellido,
      'correo' => $correo,
      'telefono' =>$telefono,
      'nivel' => $nivel,
      'universidad' => $universidad,
      'fecha' => $fecha));
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `PDO::quote()` instead of the deprecated (and in your case totally unecessary because you're using a prepared statement) `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: Your live site probaly has error messages suppressed. You will need to look at the server logs or place a print or other statement after the '$data->execute' to see what is actually happening.

Comment: Might be a PHP version issue. Are you sure you have the same version locally and on the server?

Comment: @nietonfir Good point! That's a copy and paste crime done in a rush

Comment: @nietonfir the problem was the *mysel_real_escape_string()* Deleted it and its fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your placeholder don't match in the execute statement:

```
$data->execute(array(
    ':nombre' => $nombre,
    ':apellido' => $apellido,
    ':correo' => $correo,
    ':telefono' =>$telefono,
    ':nivel' => $nivel,
    ':universidad' => $universidad,
    ':fecha' => $fecha
));
```

[edit] Updating it with the solution from my comment:

> Use PDO::quote() instead of the deprecated (and in your case totally
>   unecessary because you're using a prepared statement)
>   mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: The insert is not the issue, the issue is that no information is being sent from one page to the other, its not passing the **isset** check. However your insert statement does look more elegant